# How to use va_start()?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

In a function with variable arguments, we initialize an object of type va_list ,'ap' with the function va_start() as:

```
void va_start(va_list ap, parmN);
```

I don't understand
 
1.what type of objects can be passed as parMN(last known parameter). I've done with examples of passing integers, strings with format specifiers, structures etc.

2. How the parMN describes the following optional parameters.

Comment: See the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.4). In short: 1. `va_start` is a macro; macros have no concept of *type*; they work their magic with source text; 2. the following optional parameters are described with `va_arg` (also a macro)

Comment: [Some light reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) (examples are at the bottom). Bookmark that site, btw, for all your future C and C++ needs.

Comment: I've checked it already. Couldnt understand.. "macros have no concept of type;" that must be the point.

Comment: Indeed. They're about straight up substitution more than anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard says that [`va_start()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1) is actually a macro, not a function, so it can do things a function couldn't. The details are highly implementation dependent but you could imagine that it takes the address of parmN to determine the stack address of the next parameter. There's no need for `va_start()` to know about the types of the following parameters because that information is passed to `va_arg()`, which is another macro.

Comment: now i understand. I have been missing that va_start() is a macro ,not a function.

Comment: @KewalTakhellambam — the `va_start()` and `va_arg()` macros have to be macros because the second argument is the name of a type, and you can't pass type names to functions.