# How va_start() macro works?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to know how the `va_start(ap, parmN)` macro works? I've read that `parmN` is number of optional arguments that is being passed, but at some places I noticed that `const char *pointer` is passed as `parmN`. I want to know how `va_start()` work and why it work in above both cases?

I've read this [How to use va_start()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036703/how-to-use-va-start) but I'm unable to understand as it has no good explanation and people are referring to same sentence quoted from the standard which say very little about `va_start()` working.

I'll be glad if someone explain this.

Comment: It is architecture-dependent. If you really want to know ,you could study the macro (src) or look at the generated assembler code.

Comment: In general `parmN` is not the number of optional arguments. It is just the last argument before `...`. It could mean anything depending on the application. Please clarify your question. Do you want to know how to use `va_start`, or how it achieves what it needs to achieve? The latter is architecture-dependent.

Comment: Related: [How are variable arguments implemented in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12371450/440558)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. First I'll want to know how to use `va_start()`.

Comment: There is an example for `va_start()` usage in the linux manpage.

Comment: You pass it two arguments, `ap` and the last named parameter of the function before `...`. That's all there is to it. There is no wiggle room at all.